# If the split fails then do something else?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to order my dates in a table by Ascending and Descending i have managed to get this to work by implementing the following code;

```
fp.onCommand.subscribe(function (e, args) {
        context._dataView.sort(function (a, b) {
            var c1 = a[args.column.field].split('/');
            var c2 = b[args.column.field].split('/');

                return c1[2] - c2[2] || c1[1] - c2[1] || c1[0] - c2[0];

        }, args.command === "sort-asc");
    });
```

However, this now will not sort the rest of my columns (which include names, numbers, decimals). When i sort any column that isnt a date it fails at my `split`. Here is the code that i had originally that sorted every column perfectly but not the date;

```
fp.onCommand.subscribe(function (e, args) {
        context._dataView.sort(function (a, b) {
            var c1 = a[args.column.field];
            var c2 = b[args.column.field];

            if (c1 > c2) {
                c1 = c1.toString().toLowerCase();
                return 1;
            }

            if (c2 > c1) {
                c2 = c2.toString().toLowerCase();
                return -1;
            }
        }, args.command === "sort-asc");
    });
```

I need to somehow get the dates to sort whilst allowing me to sort the many other columns. If possible i need to write the code for something like if the split doesnt work then do the second part of my code.

If possible i need to keep everything so i need to have the exact code that is formatting the date but i also need the `toString` `toLowerCase` and my `c1 > c2` and so on.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A `.split` cannot fail.

Comment: it fails when there isnt anything to split.

Comment: No, it doesn’t _fail_ then either; quote MDN: _“If separator is not found or is omitted, the array contains one element consisting of the entire string.”_ What might fail is your attempt to access array elements that don’t exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check whether both strings are dates before implementing the date comparison. If they are both dates, `split` and return what you're already doing - else, if neither are dates, use your original algorithm. If one is a date and the other isn't, then return either 1 or -1, depending on whether you want dates at the top or at the bottom:

```
const isDate = item => typeof item === 'string' && item.includes('/');
context._dataView.sort(function (a, b) {
  const c1 = a[args.column.field];
  const c2 = b[args.column.field];
  const aIsDate = isDate(c1)
  const bIsDate = isDate(c2);
  if (aIsDate && bIsDate) {
    const c1d = c1.split('/');
    const c2d = c2.split('/');
    return c1d[2] - c2d[2] || c1d[1] - c2d[1] || c1d[0] - c2d[0];
  } else if (!aIsDate && !bIsDate) {
    // Neither are dates:
    return c1 > c2 ? 1 : -1;
  } else if (aIsDate && !bIsDate) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    // bIsDate and !aIsDate
    return -1
  }
}, args.command === "sort-asc");
```

Comment: is there anyway to keep my `toString` and `toLowerCase`?

Comment: Of course, just insert the logic you want into the `return <some sorting algorithm for non-dates>;`

Comment: And how would i write that? sorry i am having a brain malfunction

Comment: Actually, there doesn't seem to be any need for it at all, because your second code block never uses the reassigned `c1` or `c2`, and you say it works already - so just return the `1` or `-1` depending on `c1 > c2` or vice versa

Comment: Yes i understand however, i need to put my two code blocks together otherwise it just doesnt work or i simply cant get it to work. Any ideas? So your saying i find out if its a date first and then i can put my second code block in somewere? But i am not sure were?

Comment: For example, `return c1 > c2 ? 1 : -1` if that's the sort of comparison you want for non-dates (that's what your original code simplifies to, after all)

Comment: Ok so i have implemented the code but it now does not order the date correctly and i still get an error `UncaughtTypeError: a[args.column.field].split is not a function`? When trying to sort a column that doesnt have a "/".

Comment: Oh, so you have some non-strings in there as well, so you can't `split` unconditionally - well, same sort of thing, check whether it's a string *and* a date, and if so, use `split`, otherwise use your original algorithm

Comment: Can you edit your question to show me an example of this? If possible i dont want to be too much trouble but i have been on this for about a week and i need it to be fixed and i cant seem to crack it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183791/discussion-between-connorg98-and-certainperformance).

Answer (score 1):

Technically, a `split()` function cannot fail. If you try to split something that's not having the splittable character, you can try checking if the array length is just one.

Something like this:

```js
var a = "Hello";
var b = "Hello World";

function splitter(s) {
  var ar = s.split(" ");
  if (typeof ar == "object")
    if (ar.length > 1)
      console.log("Split Succeeded");
    else
      console.log("Split Failed");
  else
    console.log("Something wrong happened!");
}

splitter(a);
splitter(b);
```